# MySQL before trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I got this two tables:

```
   CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
   `id_reservation` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
   `reserved_date` date NOT NULL,
   `id_event` int(11) NOT NULL,   
   FOREIGN KEY (`id_event`) REFERENCES `event` 
   )

   CREATE TABLE `event` (
   `id_event` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
   `begin_date` date NOT NULL,
   `end_date` date NOT NULL,   
   )
```

Basically I insert a `reservation` that has a single `reserved_date`. The `reservation` is related to the `event`, that has a `begin_date` and an `end_date`.

I need to check that `reserved_date` is included (y <= x <= z) in the  `begin_date` and `end_date` of that particular `event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON reservation
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE id_event_var INT DEFAULT NULL;
  SELECT id_event INTO id_event_var FROM `event` WHERE id_event = new.id_event AND new.reserved_date >= begin_date AND new.reserved_date <= end_date;
  IF id_event_var IS NULL THEN
    ... -- wrong date!
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: It returns error #1064 on line 6.
What kind of statement do I have to write after "IF id_event_var IS NULL THEN"?

Comment: Write your code here. For example you may throw an error, e.g.: 'CALL unlnown_function();'

Comment: Ok, let's think I want to throw a feedback for that error, for example i want to print out: "Sorry, you cannot". How can i do it?

Comment: In general, how do I throw error in order to stop the INSERT query?

Comment: Call unknown stored procedure or try this for MySQL 5.5 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913999/custom-errors-in-mysql-trigger/8914094#8914094