# Custom errors in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server, raiseerror

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [raise error within MySql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function)

In MsSQL I can raise a custom error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR__TABLE__DisableRowOnDelete]
ON [dbo].[TABLE]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Data cannot be deleted.', 16, 1);
END
```

How might I do that in MySQL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function

Comment: @weston before making the question see if already exists in SO.

Comment: @aF I'm glad I didn't, or I wouldn't have found out about SIGNAL

Comment: @aF. Note that the other question highlighted is 3 years old with no accepted answer. So I think it was acceptable to ask this again. (Although I don't deny totally missing it when looking though the list of matching questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 5.5 you can use a [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement, e.g. -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TR__TABLE__DisableRowOnDelete()
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Data cannot be deleted.';
END
```